# Change My contact page To Responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have created an html page (Contact page) which is Working well but its Not Responsive. I have checked  and applied media query full CSS its working Responsive.after that check my system not working  desktop application now working responsive? how to set my code both  desktop and mobile device  in responsive ?

MY css code:

```
        body{
                font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size:14px;
            }
            p, h1, form, button{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
            .spacer{clear:both; height:1px;}

            /* ----------- My Form ----------- */
            .myform{
                margin:0 auto;
                width:566px;
                padding:14px;
            }

            /* ----------- contact ----------- */
            #contact{
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #C6C6C6;
                border: 2px solid #8B8B8B;
                border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                -op-border-radius: 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            }
            #contact h1 {
                font-weight:bold;
                margin-bottom:8px;
            }
            #contact p{
                font-size:11px;
                color:#666666;
                margin-bottom:20px;
                border-bottom:solid 1px #7E7E7E;
                padding-bottom:10px;
            }
            #contact label{
                display:block;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:right;
                width:193px;
                float:left;
            }
            #contact .small{
                color:#666666;
                display:block;
                font-size:11px;
                font-weight:normal;
                text-align:right;
                width:193px;
            }
            #contact input,#contact textarea{
                float:left;
                border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
                width:284px;
                margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
                border-radius: 15px;
                -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                -op-border-radius: 15px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            #contact input{
                height: 25px;
                padding: 4px 10px;
            }
            #contact textarea{
                padding: 10px 10px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            /* ----------- Form Button ----------- */
            #contact button {
               background: #2c3e4a;
               background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#919496), to(#2c3e4a));
               background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #919496, #2c3e4a);
               background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #919496, #2c3e4a);
               background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #919496, #2c3e4a);
               background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #919496, #2c3e4a);
               padding: 5px 10px;
               -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
               -moz-border-radius: 15px;
               border-radius: 15px;
               margin-left: 315px;
               color: white;
               font-size: 20px;
               text-decoration: none;
               vertical-align: middle;
            }
            #contact button:hover {
               background: #3d4b54;
               color: #ccc;
            }
```

contact html page

```
  <div id="form-wrapper" class="myform">
             <div id="contact" class="myform">

            <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="mail.php">

                <h1>Contact Us</h1>

                <label for="name">Name
                    <span class="small">Add your name</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" id="name" />

                <label for="email">Email
                    <span class="small">Add a valid address</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" id="email" />

                <label for="phone">Phone
                    <span class="small">Add valid 10 digit your mobile no.</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Number" id="phone" />

                <label for="message">Message
                    <span class="small">Write something to us</span>
                </label>
                <textarea placeholder="Write something to us" name="message" id="message"  rows="5"></textarea>

                <button type="submit">Send</button>
                <div class="spacer"></div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

how to change it Responsive design? please any idea ?now working in desktop   well.  but  not Responsive mobile device ? any idea about it?

Comment: Use media queries - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: i have used media query  its working mobile  but after that check in desktop that time design changed  not working well  in desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 565px){
.myform{

                width:100%;
                padding-right:15px;
                padding-left:15px;
            }
}
```

try this and edit your inner div's width by percentage

Comment: brother i have used media working mobile responsive after check code not prepare working in desktop screen

Comment: nan media query myform use panan brother screen resize mobile size ku work aguathu but again nan periya screen la partha  design  work agala.  design issues iruku brother

Comment: brother ipa na my form ku  media apply pana  thirumpa my from   without css  set panama brother ?

Comment: media query la um css irukanum then normal css um irukanum.media query css responsive la eduthukum. normal css desktop la eduthukum.

Comment: ila bro  trying..enga css apply panunam path  irukan bro

Comment: neega mela pothurukathutha full css a

Comment: ama brother athan full css

Comment: <div id="form-wrapper" class="myform">
             <div id="contact" class="myform"> 2 div laum class="myform" iruku oru div la eduthu vitutu try panuga bro..

Answer (score 0):

Use css3 media queries and you can define the CSS according to mobile device width

Adding to Dinesh's answer, you need to keep both the class in your CSS file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)
    {
        .myform
        {
            width: 200px;
        }


    }
    .myform
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 566px;
        padding: 14px;
    }
```

Then you can resize the browser to check the effect. Resize to less than 500 px, media queries will be applied. Maximize the browser `.myform` class will be applied which is not in media query